# Barplot with ggplot2 (R), one variable and one modality from another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't find a solution to what seems to me to be a small problem: do you know how to make a bar plot with ggplot2 that links a variable (in this case age classes) with a modality of another variable ?

Here is my code :

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

age10 <- c("18-34","35-54", "55+", "55+","35-54","18-34","18-34","35-54","35-54","35-54")
relation <- c("stable","non stable", "non stable", "stable", "stable", "stable", "non     stable", "non stable", "stable", "stable")

df <- data.frame(age10,relation)

df1 <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(age10, relation) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) 

ggplot(df1) +
  aes(fill = relation, y = n, x = age10) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
  labs(x = "Age group", y = "Percentage", 
       title = "relational status by age group")``
```

---

the barplot gives me the percentage of stable and non stable relationships stacked, whereas I'd like it to show only the percentage of non stable relationships (or stable) for each age group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to compute the percentages manually, then you could use e.g. `facet_wrap` to show the percentages separately for each `relation`:

```
df1 <-
  df %>%
  group_by(age10, relation) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), relation = str_squish(relation))

ggplot(df1) +
  aes(fill = relation, y = pct, x = age10) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
  facet_wrap(~relation) +
  labs(
    x = "Age group", y = "Percentage",
    title = "relational status by age group"
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** And if you want oto display only one category filter your dataset and of course remove the `facet_wrap`:

```
df1 <-
  df %>%
  group_by(age10, relation) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), relation = str_squish(relation)) %>%
  filter(relation == "stable")

ggplot(df1) +
  aes(fill = relation, y = pct, x = age10) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
  labs(
    x = "Age group", y = "Percentage",
    title = "relational status by age group"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan, as there are only two modalities, the total frequency of both is 100%, so it would be more convenient if I could display only one of the two

Comment: I see. Not a big deal., In that case you could filter the data after computing the percentages. See my edit.